# Get all configuration fields in group

Tags: magento2, configuration

I have made 2 example groups, which look like this:

```
first_group
   first_field_1
   first_field_2
   first_field_3

second_group
   second_field_1
   second_field_2
```

How can I dynamically get the fields per group (for example, using something like `$this->getGroupFields('first_group')`)?